# Is there Select Field in Material UI version 1?

Tags: material-ui

I am new to Material UI and am trying to use V1.  Is there Select Field in V1.  I can't find it. Is it replaced by something else?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As of material V1.2 :

```
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';
```

...

```
          <Select
            value={this.state.age}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            inputProps={{
              name: 'age',
              id: 'age-simple',
            }}
          >
            <MenuItem value="">
              <em>None</em>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
          </Select>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `SelectField` component in Material UI v1 is currently work in progress.
You can see the current progress [here](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/pull/7632).

I recently ported some projects to Material UI v1 and replaced select fields with radio buttons.

**Edit**
Since *v1.0.0-beta.9* the `Select`component is available.
Example usage:

```
  <Select
    value={this.state.value}
    onChange={(e) => this.setState({ value : event.target.value}) }
    input={<Input name="select" id="select-simple" />}
  >
    <MenuItem value={0}>
      <em>None</em>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
  </Select>
```

Comment: The [Select component](https://material-ui-next.com/api/select/) was released as of [version 1.0.0-beta.9](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/releases/tag/v1.0.0-beta.9).

Comment: Thank you, @KenGregory. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: An answer could also clarify that "No, there is not SelectField in version 1*". A developer has to modify any use of SelectField in code developed for earlier Material UI versions.